# Django - navigate hyperlink to a folder on disk

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I would like to click on a hyperlink in my Django template that navigates to an arbitrary URL such as `file:///C:/my_dir/folder`, this URL works if I paste it directly into the address field of a browser, but does nothing if I click on a hyperlink in my Django app that resolves to that URL. I've also tried implementing it using the template - view protocol for Django but in my view neither of these seem to work `return HttpResponse(html_filepath)` or `return render(request, html_filepath, context)`.

Returning HttpResponse simply displays the text `file:///C:/my_dir/folder` in my browser window at URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/my_app/my_dir/folder//result_filepath/`.

Returning render gives the following error:

> OSError at /my_app/C:/my_dir/folder//result_filepath/
>   [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Users\user\Documents\my_app\my_source_code\my_tool\mysite\templates\file:\C:/my_dir/folder'

My goal is to see the folder contents at the URL `file:///C:/my_dir/folder`

Comment: I solved this by generating my own HTML page to contain manually generated directory contents.

Comment: restarting the server did my job.

Comment: BTW still don't know the reason of this error.